# PHP: Object serialization working via direct file handling but not via session

Tags: php, session, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and unserialize a quite long object -- 250KB compressed -- via session but it's not working.

I've done two tests. The first one consisted on directly serialize and unserialize the object more than once for checking if the problem was the serialization *per se* but everything ran ok. The second one consisted on writing the serialized object into a file and that worked fine too.

Unfortunately it would be insane to post here or elsewhere all the code itself.

Has anyone dealed with a problem like that or suggest any other test to be done?

Comment: Why can't you post the code here? We don't need the huge object, just the PHP code that saves and restores it.

Comment: You need to post some code, or we won't be able to help. See: [help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's a setting in your server code that's preventing an upload size that big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was classes with no support to serialization like Zend_Db_Table and Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract subclasses.

When serializing objects it's needed to go as deep as possible to map every object dependency and treat them and I ended up by giving up serialize what motivated me to post the question in first place.

Thank everyone who tried helping me on this.

Answer (score 0):

have you make a instance of unserialize first?

eg

```
$a = new A;
if($_SESSION['my_a']) {
     $a = unserialize($_SESSION['my_a']);
}
```

Comment: I'm keeping the object itself on session like this: `$a = new Sample();     $_SESSION['object'] = $a; ...; $a = $_SESSION['object'];`

Answer (score 0):

Go into php.ini at: ...\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin

change: upload_max_filesize

Comment: It's not an uploaded content.